# MySQL - Find listings posted by multiple people

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a schema as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicle` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vehiclelicence` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `companyid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

insert into vehicle (vehiclelicence, userid) values ('PB1234', 1);
insert into vehicle (vehiclelicence, userid) values ('AB0987', 2);
insert into vehicle (vehiclelicence, userid) values ('UI7654', 3);
insert into vehicle (vehiclelicence, userid) values ('DV8888', 4);
insert into vehicle (vehiclelicence, userid) values ('PB1234', 2);
insert into vehicle (vehiclelicence, userid) values ('UI7654', 1);

insert into user (username, companyid) values ('Bob', 1);
insert into user (username, companyid) values ('Tim', 2);
insert into user (username, companyid) values ('Jim', 3);
insert into user (username, companyid) values ('Fred', 4);

insert into company (name) values ('Company 1');
insert into company (name) values ('Company 2');
insert into company (name) values ('Company 3');
insert into company (name) values ('Company 4');
```

Users add vehiclelicences all the time.
How can I return all vehiclelicences listed by more than one company and which company listed it?

This is the sql I have so far, but it lists all the records.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    vehicle v1
join user u on u.id = v1.userid
join company c on c.id = u.companyid
WHERE   EXISTS
(
        SELECT  1
        FROM    vehicle v2
        WHERE   v1.vehiclelicence = v1.vehiclelicence and v2.userid != v1.userid
        LIMIT 1, 1
)
order by v1.vehiclelicence
;
```

I have created a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/583c70/5/0)

This is the desired output

```
+----------------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| vehiclelicence | userid | username | companyid | companyname |
+----------------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| PB1234         | 1      | Bob      | 1         | Company 1   |
| PB1234         | 2      | Tim      | 2         | Company 2   |
| UI7654         | 3      | Jim      | 3         | Company 3   |
| UI7654         | 1      | Bob      | 1         | Company 1   |
+----------------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Strawberry - Thanks for the hint - I have updated with a fiddle and my first attempt

Comment: WHERE   v1.vehiclelicence = v1.vehiclelicence - a typo here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHERE   v1.vehiclelicence = v1.vehiclelicence - a typo here..and remove the limit and it works.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    vehicle v1
join user u on u.id = v1.userid
join company c on c.id = u.companyid
WHERE   EXISTS
(
        SELECT  1
        FROM    vehicle v2
        WHERE   v1.vehiclelicence = v2.vehiclelicence and v2.userid != v1.userid
        #LIMIT 1, 1
)
order by v1.vehiclelicence
;
```

OR start the offset from 0

```
SELECT  *
FROM    vehicle v1
join user u on u.id = v1.userid
join company c on c.id = u.companyid
WHERE   EXISTS
(
        SELECT  1
        FROM    vehicle v2
        WHERE   v1.vehiclelicence = v2.vehiclelicence and v2.userid != v1.userid
        LIMIT 0, 1
)
order by v1.vehiclelicence
;
```

either way

```
+----+----------------+--------+----+----------+-----------+----+-----------+
| id | vehiclelicence | userid | id | username | companyid | id | name      |
+----+----------------+--------+----+----------+-----------+----+-----------+
|  1 | PB1234         |      1 |  1 | Bob      |         1 |  1 | Company 1 |
|  5 | PB1234         |      2 |  2 | Tim      |         2 |  2 | Company 2 |
|  6 | UI7654         |      1 |  1 | Bob      |         1 |  1 | Company 1 |
|  3 | UI7654         |      3 |  3 | Jim      |         3 |  3 | Company 3 |
+----+----------------+--------+----+----------+-----------+----+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Ah Thanks @P.Salmon! Much appreciated - Can't believe I missed the typo! Working now! Thanks!